# Inserting data from CSV in mutiple tables via ASP.NET (C#), SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, csv

I have an CSV file with 7 columns, which a user has to upload so it can be added in the database.
I found some help in reading the CSV and putting all the info in a single table, however, the data has to be spread over three tables.

My code for inserting all the data to 1 table:

```
        protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] { 
        new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Artist", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Years", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Position", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Senddate", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Sendfrom", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Sendtill", typeof(string))});


        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string cell in row.Split(';'))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ingevoerd";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it takes 7 columns, and puts them in the table [dbo].[ingevoerd]

How can i split the data to put the column 'Title' and 'Years' in a table called Song, 'Artist' in a table called Artiest, and 'Position', 'Senddate', 'Sendfrom' an 'Sendtill' in a table called Lijst?

For more information, put down a comment.

Comment: imho you should use SSIS for this task instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho this is not the best way to handle this upload because the content is not flat data you can bulk upload in a breeze; there are many entitiest (at least 3) that should be linked.

i would go with the 'old style' approach of calling a insert for each row with proper parameters.

you are already looping through the Whole recordset when reading the CSV so i would make something like:

```
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction())
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Transaction = tran;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "your_sp_name_here";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@artist", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                // other parameters follow
                // ...

                string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
                foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                    {
                        // for every row call the command and fill in the parameters with proper values
                        cmd.Parameters["@title"].Value = row[0];
                        cmd.Parameters["@artist"].Value = row[1];
                        // ...
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                // when done commit the transaction
                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

inside your stored procedure handle the 'split' of the data in the relevant tables taking all the steps required to avoid duplicates and maybe linking the data among the tables:

```
create procedure your_sp_name_here(@title nvarchar(50), @artist nvarchar(50), @year int)
as
begin
 -- add logic & checks here if needed
 -- ...
 -- ...

 -- if everything is ok insert the rows
 insert into songs (title, year) values (@title, @year)
 insert into Artiest (Artist) values (@artist)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will take a look at this and try to implement it!

Comment: When you have a lot of data I wrould also recommend using a StreamReader instread of reading all content

Comment: another option is to use a [custom library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) that greatly simplify the interaction with CSV files

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into column mappings?

Check out stackoverflow.com/questions/17469349/mapping-columns-in-a-datatable-to-a-sql-table-with-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: Nope, i am not known with column mappings, gonna look at that though.